# What is the difference between ram cache and cache ram?

Tags: caching, memory-management

If I'm not mistaken, ram cache is used to speed up file operations on a drive, and cache ram is used to speed up cpu itself? Can someone clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both concepts are quite different.

Ram cache describes a *software* mechanism to speed up access to data with a long access time by  duplicating information in the ram. It is used by operating systems that keep in the ram memory a copy of the most frequently used blocks of a disk or a network file system. But the same mechanism is also used by web servers or proxies to keep track of frequently used web pages, by sql servers, etc. Disk access are typically ~1ms, while ram access time is at last 10000 times faster. And the gain is even larger when network is involved.

Cache memory is a *hardware* concept. It is a fast memory associated to the processor that aims to accelerate memory access. Typical memory access time can be reduced by 2 orders of magnitude (from 100 ns to 1 ns) when using a cache memory. All memory accesses can be accelerated, including if the data is part of a "ram cache".

The size of the cache is determined by your hardware. The cache memory acts largely independently of the programmer and there is no convenient way to decide which data are kept in the cache. (but knowing how a cache works is an important part of software optimisation).
For ram caches, it is completely different, the programmer decides the size of the "ram cache" and the way data is entered or ejected from the cache.